# I need a python REGEX to split a file by delimiters (begin, end) that can have multiple occurences

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python. I would like to split a file that contains n sections by using the delimiters "BEGIN" and "END".

The file contains:

```
BEGIN
ABC ABC ABC
END
BEGIN
XYZ
XYZ
END
BEGIN
A B C
END
```

With the file above, I would like to have as output:

file 1:

```
BEGIN
ABC ABC ABC
END
```

file 2:

```
BEGIN
XYZ
XYZ
END
```

file 3:

```
BEGIN
A B C
END
```

I think this can be done with a REGEX but I haven't been able to find the pattern that will identify the 3 groups (BEGIN ... END) in the example above.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
import re
with open('original.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

m = re.findall("BEGIN.*?END", s, re.DOTALL)

n = 1
for x in m:
    with open(f"{n}.txt", "w", encoding='utf8' ) as f:
        f.write(x)
    n+=1
```

---

The above will create 3 files

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Containing the text `BEGIN ... END`.

Comment: Care to comment the down vote?

Comment: This solution is also good. Thank you Pedro Lobito. It is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.` to match newlines and with the `re.MULTILINE` flag to allow `^` and `$` to match the beginning and the end of a line, assuming the content of the input file is stored in the variable `content`:

```
re.findall('^BEGIN$.*?^END$', content, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Thank you blhsing. It is highly appreciated.